# The opposite of "crash" for a stock?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that describes that action of making a stock price go up by a lot in a short period of time. The opposite would be "crash" which makes the stock price fall by a lot in a short amount of time.

**Edit:** I'm going to try to clear this up. I'm not getting confused about for *which* action I'm looking for a word. I am making a game in which players interact with a virtual stock market. However, there is an "admin" who is in complete and total control of the market, which *does not exist in the real world*, and I understand this. I do not need words that describe the stock price suddenly rising or falling. I need words that describe the **action of causing** the price to rise or fall. I realize that this does not happen in the real stock market, but it does happen in my game.

Comment: Are you looking for the verb that indicates the actor is *causing* the stock price to rise or the verb where the stock is the actor?  You seem to be asking for the former, but your example *crash* is more the later as you don't usually say "he crashed the stock" but rather "the stock crashed"

Comment: I am looking for the verb about causing it. I'm making a game and the admin needs to be able to "crash" or "___" each stock.

Comment: People don't crash stocks. Stocks crash. So you might want to ask a new question to cover both of them. (**EDIT:** Or accept that the admin can "crash" or "rally/surge" the stock, with the understanding that the words don't match the situation properly.)

Comment: I never heard of speculators *crashing* stock prices. I think OP is getting confused with the fact that we speak of markets / share prices that *crash* or *boom*. The normal term for deliberate action is *drive up/down the share price*.

Comment: @roviuser Crash is something that happens to a stock, but you need an Admin to be able to change the value of the stock. Does Lower and Raise stock value work?

Comment: @jprete I've added details to clarify. Yes, in my situation, people _do_ crash stocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with allowing the admin to *tank* and *boost* the stock.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are referring to the action that the stock is taking (and not the *cause* of the rise), I've most commonly heard [rally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rally_%28stock_market%29):

> A rally is a period of sustained increases in the prices of stocks, bonds or indexes

Comment: In my question I clearly say "word that describes that action of making a stock price go up." I don't mean the stock rising, but the act of causing the stock to rise.

Comment: @roviuser obviously it wasn't as clear as you thought since multiple people asked for clarification about it.  Also, please keep in mind that a lot of the askers here are not native English speakers, so it's not always safe to take the wording in their questions too literally.  But, you might try some more generic term like "boost".

Comment: Also, this might be helpful, a common real-world case where this happens is a "stock repurchase" or "stock buyback" (where a company buys its own stock to boost demand for it and raise the price).   You might be able to find some news articles about those with a good descriptive term.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *[soar](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/soar_1?q=soar)* or *[surge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/surge_2)*. However these are intransitive verbs so we say *the prices soared* or *the prices surged*.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know how formal this answer has to be so I will simply suggest the word skyrocketed, for **sudden** and **huge** increase in stock price.

E.g. the stock price skyrocketed today at 11am

You can say "the stock prices crashed", as you can "the stock prices skyrocketed", so I think it can be a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

A *rally* is when prices steadily increase.

A *surge* or *soar* is when they increase suddenly.

This is applicable for all prices, (gold, fuel, etc), not just stocks

Answer (score 0):

*Inflate* might fit the bill, although I prefer the monosyllabic symmetry of [saritonin](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48328/23688)'s *tank* and *boost*.

Answer (score 0):

I hear and read the phrase "rocket" in this context a lot.  "Rally" tends to be more specific to a stock which has been lagging, and is bouncing back to or beyond expected levels.

Answer (score 0):

> I need words that describe the action of causing the price to rise or fall.

One word for an action to cause either a rise or fall would be "manipulate."  One could hypothetically manipulate the market to cause a crash, a dramatic sudden fall in price, or a bubble, a sudden rise in price based on speculation.